# unable to connect to wifi on my HP G3 250 Laptop

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I am unable to connect to wifi on my HP G3 250 Laptop. I have tried almost everything on the internet(driver install/uninstall,remove/change SSN,router configuration,system format).I have even get it checked by HP service center guy just to make sure its not hardware issue, even he couldn't rectify.

Please note , i can connect all the other devices using same router.On Laptop it throws an error message as follows:
"windows was unable to connect to .........."

Laptop : HP G3 250
OS: windows 7
Router : netgear n150 wireless adsl2+ modem router dgn1000
Broadband : Mtnl Mumbai

I would sincerely appreciate your help here.

Comment: does the problem persist in safe mode? (To get into safe mode, press F12, F10, DEL, or another key repeatedly until you enter the boot menu.

Answer (score 1):

USB dongle is possibly the best method, but before you do - Download the ubuntu ISO, place on CD/USB (Rufus is great for USB) and start the installer - Don't install, just see if ubuntu picks up your wifi card and can join your network - If it can then your laptop has a driver issue with the built in adapter - Then you are on your way to fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I had this problem with a HP laptop it was a hardware problem in the laptop. I bought a USB WiFi dongle and the problem was solved. -- Just a thought of a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers/suggestions.

After all the research on internet and on laptop, problem was with wifi/bluetooth card(Had to pay around 2000 INR for new card & installation charges). Please keep this also in mind if anyone ever come across such issue.